# how to download files & folder with all its content from http using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to download file from http using powershell, however, it never downloads the complete file. Also, please suggest, how can I download the whole folder from http site with all its content, I could able to see some examples on the site, however, since I am new to powershell, I am unable to completely make it work for me.

I need to download zip file(500 mb) from http to one of my server to install software after download.

```
$webclient=New-object system.net.webclient
$weclient.downloadfile("http://mysite/file.zip","c:\testfolder\file.zip")
```

zip file should download, however, it starts downloading, but never download complete 500 mb file, sometimes it downloads 10 mb, sometimes 20 mb file. I am using Windows 2012 standard for this purpose. If I try to download small files, it downloads completely, however not the 500 mb zip file.

Comment: When it fails to download the complete file, what happens? Are there any error message that you will copy and paste the text into the question?

Comment: It doesnt give me any error message, when I check the file size, it is not the complete file.

Comment: What is the value of `$LASTEXITCODE`?

Comment: $LASTEXITCODE is 0

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer:**

Since this is a network issue, you could try a forever loop until the file you download is complete:

`do{sleep 3;(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://mysite/file.zip','C:\testfolder\file.zip')}while(!$?);`

It essentially sleeps for 3 seconds in the beginning, attempts to download the file using the webclient. The while condition is to check if the webclient command returns a `false` which `!$?` is short hand for and then repeats itself if it is false. Now, if the webclient command is completing successfully and you're still getting an incomplete file, there might be something else in play. But we'll figure it out once we get there :).

Let me know if this works, this should retry until it is finished.

**Old Answer:**

````
If the website you're downloading from is using TLS, you should enable it in your current session using the following:

``` [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12```

Though it seems the website might be only ```http```, this first part might not be needed.

Next, I recommend using ```Invoke-WebRequest``` to download the file. It's simpler than using the webclient.

```Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://mysite/file.zip" -Outfile "c:\testfolder\file.zip"```

Try this out and let us know if it works.
````

Comment: the website is not using TLS. I have also tried the invoke-webrequest, but it is also not downloading the complete file. Is there any way to ensure the file is downloaded completely or resume download in case of any network interruption, is there is any?

Comment: Could tell us more about the server you’re downloading from? I am able to download a file that’s over 500mbs with invoke-webrequest without issues.

Comment: I think its a network interruption or something on OS which is causing this.The transfer is not consistent, if I download some mb files, it downloads, but not 500 mb or so. I am downloading from the site hosted on apache to Windows server. When I try downloading from linux server on the same network, it works fine using curl and I am able to download 500 to 1 gb file.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure the data transfer resumes in case of interruption for any reason, I have also tried bit transfer method, however, it is also not working. For example, I tried:



Import-Module BitsTransfer

Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output

Comment: @Mickey I just updated my answer, try to use that for retries and let me know if it finishes.

Comment: I tried new method, it did not work. It just downloaded 35 mb file. :(

Comment: There seems to be some type of restriction to your network. Are all the incomplete files around 35mbs? I would do a packet capture while you’re downloading. Let me know what you see in the capture.

Comment: I think something related to NIC driver or OS, as I tried from Linux server on the same network and it worked fine using curl. I have tried increasing MTU size on NIC, still same. I am trying to download from apache to windows server.